# Import "Microsoft.WebTools.Scaffolding.Core.ScaffolderFactory.FactoryConfigEvaluator" could not be satisfied

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview - Version 16.8.0 Preview 1.0 . I try to scaffolding ASP.NET Core Identity files. I catch error

> Import
> "Microsoft.WebTools.Scaffolding.Core.ScaffolderFactory.FactoryConfigEvaluator"
> could not be satisfied.

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages`

Find something like this

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Scaffolding,version=16.6.741.31162,chip=neutral,language=en-US`

For example, full path

```
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Scaffolding,version=16.6.741.31162,chip=neutral,language=en-US"
```

Close Visual Studio. Delete all files inside this folder.
Launch Visual Studio Installer. choose Repair.

[image]

caution: disadvantage, the download file size is too large (4.8 GB)

[image]

See more at https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1364

Comment: I followed your steps. And I deleted my VS. I had to reselect all my packages :(